# Acessar um diretório por um jar

Tags: java, jar

Eu criei um código que utiliza um arquivo que fica localizado em um determinado diretório (resources). Quando eu rodo esse código pelo eclipse, esse diretório é encontrado e todas as ações do código são feitas. Porém, ao gerar um `.jar` desse código, ele não encontra o diretório especificado. Preciso de alguma maneira acessar esse diretório pelo arquivo `.jar`.

Segue parte do meu código:

```
teste = Json.criarJson(teste, json);

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = new Date();

CopyTemplate.copyfile("src/resources/StatusTestesGPES_template.xls", "src/resources/StatusTestesGPES_"+ dateFormat.format(date)+".xls", teste);
```

Copyfile:

```
public static void copyfile(String ORIcaminho, String DEScaminho, Test[] teste) throws InvalidFormatException, ParseException
{
      try
      {
          File origem = new File(ORIcaminho);
          File destino = new File(DEScaminho);
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origem);

          //For Overwrite the file.
          OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destino);

          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
          {
              out.write(buf, 0, len);
          }

          in.close();
          out.close();
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage() , "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
}
```

Quando "rodo" pelo `.jar` aparece o erro:

> "src/resources/StatusTestesGPES_template.xls (o sist. não pode encontrar o caminho)"

Comment: Você quer acessar arquivos compilados dentro do jar, é isso?

Comment: isso mesmo... o "StatusTestesGPES_template.xls" é um desses arquivos por exemplo

Comment: Você não pode mover arquivos dentro do proprio jar, teria que recriá-lo para isso.

Comment: como assim? não entendi

Comment: Você está tentando mover arquivos dentro do proprio jar, isso não é possivel sem "repacotar" ele, ou seja, você precisaria criar o jar novamente.

Comment: Não estou tentando mover. Eu leio do arquivo "template" e crio um novo arquivo

Answer (score 1):

O motivo do erro provavelmente é por você estar informando um caminho somente reconhecido pelo eclipse, pois a pasta `src` é criada apenas no projeto para armazenar a estrutura de pacotes e arquivos `.java` criados dentro da IDE.

Além disso, você está usando a classe `File` para ler arquivos internos ao jar. Esta classe foi feita para ler arquivos no sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional em execução, para ler arquivos do jar, você precisa acessar o *ClassLoader* e dele obter um stream, utilizando [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String pathname)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), pois o arquivo só existe em memória, no contexto de execução da aplicação, e não como um arquivo do sistema operacional.

Outro problema que notei no seu código é que você parece querer copiar arquivos dentro do próprio jar em execução, e isso não é possível, afinal, se o jar está em execução pela JVM, como você espera poder alterá-lo? Ao invés de escrever dentro do jar, você pode copiar o arquivo para um lugar comum externo ao jar, como a pasta de usuário. Veja um exemplo básico:

```
//cria um stream do arquivo dentro do jar para manipulação
InputStream in = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/example/res/textfile.txt");
//caminho do novo arquivo a ser criado na pasta de usuario do sistema em execução
String externalPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "externaltxt.txt";
//efetua a cópia do arquivo interno do jar para fora dele
Files.copy(in, Paths.get(externalPath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
in.close();
```